# How to Insert Options with Ajax while Having Option Group in select2?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a multiselect dropdown with below data:

```
var fruitArray = [];
var fruitGreen = [];
var fruitNotGreen = [];

fruitGreen = {
    "text": "Green",
    "children": [
        { "id": "Watermelon", "text": "Watermelon" },
        { "id": "Lime", "text": "Lime" },
        { "id": "Guava", "text": "Guava" },
        { "id": "Avocado", "text": "Avocado" },
        { "id": "Kiwi", "text": "Kiwi" },
    ]};
fruitNotGreen = {
    "text": "Not Green",
    "children": [
        { "id": "Apple", "text": "Apple" },
        { "id": "Orange", "text": "Orange" },
        { "id": "Berries", "text": "Berries" },
        { "id": "Grape", "text": "Grape" },
        { "id": "Pineapple", "text": "Pineapple" },
    ]};
fruitArray.push(fruitGreen, fruitNotGreen);

$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "-- Select Fruits --",
    allowClear: true,
    maximumSelectionLength: 50,
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    data: fruitArray,
    multiple: true,
    closeOnSelect: false
});
```

How to Insert Options with Ajax while Having Option Group? Please help

I'm using select2 multiple dropdown from https://select2.org